# Confusion in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Look at the table (e.g TRClient)

```
| ID | clientid | sId |   startdate  |  enddate     |
|----|----------|-----|--------------|--------------|
| 1  |  10      |  1  | '2011-06-01' | '2012-05-31' |
| 2  |  25      |  3  | '2011-06-01' | '2012-05-31' |
| 3  |  10      |  1  | '2012-06-01' | '2013-05-31' |
```

I want `clientid` whose `enddate` is **not** greater than or equal to it's previous record's `enddate`
(relationship between two records can be determine by `sId`).

I have made the following query:
(here I am using loop for each client id in TRClient)

```
Select clientid from TRClient where clientId = 10 and sId = 1 and not (endDate >= '2012-05-31')
```

I want to check record for highest id for each client (If clientid and sId are same then it should check only for one record whose id is greater. e.g. in the given table if we are talking about `clientid = 10` and `sid = 1` we will get two rows`(id = 1 and id = 3)`. Here I want to check `enddate >= '2012-05-31' for id = 3)`

Comment: You can simplify this by ordering it in ascending order, such that every next row will always be equal to or greater than the current row, but never less than that.

Comment: Are the columns of `startdate` and `enddate` of type `date`? Because if they are string, like it looks at first sight, you won't be able to compare them in such format. I believe, the only trustworthy string comparison of the dates would be in format yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius yes, both columns' datatype is **datetime**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wanted to do:

```
SELECT ClientId FROM TRClient WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM TRClient
WHERE ClientId = 10 AND sId = 1) AND StartDate >= '2012-05-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the columns `datetime` in the database and you want to compare them, then you need a valid compare values as well.

Try this:

```
SELECT clientid 
FROM TRClient 
WHERE clientId = 10 
  AND sId = 1 
  AND DATEDIFF(n, startDate,'05/31/2012') > 0
```

If you write a string format like '05/31/2012' sql server try to convert it automatically. 
Depending on server locales you might handle month/day.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
select * from TRClient trc1 join TRClient trc2 on trc1.id = trc2.sid 
where trc1.startDate <= trc2.endDate
```

or

```
select * from TRClient trc1 where exists
(select 1 from TRClient trc2 where trc2.sid = trc1.id and trc1.startDate <= trc2.endDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ClientID
FROM   TRClient AS TRC1
WHERE  startDate < (SELECT EndDate
                    FROM   TRClient AS TRC2
                    WHERE  TRC2.ID = (SELECT Max(ClientID)
                                      FROM   TRClient AS TRC3
                                      WHERE  TRC3.ID < TRC1.ID))
```

I forgot to use sID and ClientID but you can add them to my code, did you get the point?